# Can not get /start after page refresh

Tags: node.js, angular

I have built a client-server application and I use MongoDB as my database.

After I start

> npm run build

and

> npm run start:prod

I am able to load the site it is working fine but after a page refresh, I am getting

> Cannot GET /start

My application structure looks like this

- dist

  - client
  - server
- package.json

**routing.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'start', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'start', component: StartComponent },
  { path: 'ai-option', component: OptionComponent },
  { path: 'deepdata', component: DeepdataComponent },
  { path: '**', component: StartComponent }

];
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

**server**

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as cors from 'cors';
import { Routes } from './routes/twitter';


class App {

  public app: express.Application;
  public route: Routes = new Routes();

  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
    this.config();
    this.route.routes(this.app);
  }

  private config(): void {
    this.app.use(cors());
    this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
    this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

    if (this.app.get('env') === 'production') {
      // loading the angular client folder or application
      this.app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../client')));
    }
  }

}

export default new App().app;
```

**package.json script**

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run server:run\" \"ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json\"",
    "server:run": "tsc -p ./server && concurrently \"tsc -w -p ./server\" \"nodemon dist/server/server.js\" ",
    "build": "ng build --prod --output-path=dist/client && npm run server:build",
    "server:build": "tsc -p ./server",
    "copyfiles": "cp -R ai dist/server/routes",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/server/server.js"
  },
```

The application is running under localhost:8000

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You need redirect all request to angular to file index.html. Some like this:

```
router.use('*', (req, res) => { 
  res.redirect('angular-dir/index.html'); 
})
```

This code need add in router file in end to file.